# Get ControllerAs alias inside base controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

We have legacy code written in AngularJS that does not use `controllerAs`.

[Sample Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uHWieK8jPEkDDMSo?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Our `BaseController` (Plunker: script.js line 19) has this code to make all class methods available in `$scope` without writing `this.$scope.method = ...`

```js
this.$scope[key] = this[key].bind(this)
```

Now since we are starting to migrate to `Controller as vm` syntax we do not need this code any more. In Plunker `NewCtrl` does not even need `$scope` injected, but because of this line we need to.

**Question**: How to find out if current controller (`NewCtrl`) is used with `controllerAs` syntax or not?

Comment: Make your code as simple as possible, it is overkill what you try to do. :)

Comment: @MaximShoustin I would if code were written from scratch. Now it's at least 90 controllers that expand same base controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app uses `ui-router`, you could use `$state` service to check if a controller is declared with `as` syntax.

`$state.get()` returns a list of all registered states. Inside each item you can check for `controllerAs` existance or 'as' inside `controller` :

```
controller: 'testCtrl as vm' or 
controllerAs: 'vm'
```

From inside a controller, you could use `$state.current` as above.